# Asp net mvc application fails after upgrade to mvc5 from mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

I had created mvc4 based app using vs2012 Framework 4.5

Upgraded the app to MVC5.

now it fails with:

> Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.AddGlobalImport(System.String)' failed

How to resolve this?

Comment: Please check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926552/attempt-by-security-transparent-method-webmatrix-webdata-preapplicationstartcod

Comment: @nemesv,Thanks, of all that prescriptions.. only the steps For upgrading from Web API to Web API 2, in global.asax, change:
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration); to
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); and update the package was neccessary.