# Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()' to access security critical method failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

We have recently upgraded our MVC3 application to MVC5 (rather, we are attempting to do so now).

The application runs successfully on some machines, but not mine. It also won't run on the web server.

I have compared the versions of the System.Web.* dlls with those on the working machine and they appear to be the same.

I have also followed the fixes from the other threads I found, with to no avail. I will have to search again to find those that I tried, but here is the first one that I remember.

- [Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926552/attempt-by-security-transparent-method-webmatrix-webdata-preapplicationstartcod)

What else would I need to change/update to prevent this problem?

Here is the error and stack trace:

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

```
System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationPart..ctor(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.String)' failed.
```

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationPart..ctor(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.String)' failed.]
   System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule() +96
   System.Web.WebPages.Administration.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +41

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.WebPages.Administration.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationPart..ctor(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.String)' failed..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +547
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.WebPages.Administration.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationPart..ctor(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.String)' failed..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9931916
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

**UPDATE**

Here is some info from my web.config

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  ...
 </assemblies>
</compilation>
<runtime>
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Forms" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Drawing" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Services" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Routing" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.Data" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what are the "fixes from other threads you found"?

Comment: I will have to look for them again. But, they had to do with the missing/incorrect versions on the dlls.

Comment: I don't know what you've tried, but I would check the MVC version numbers in both web.config and project assemblies. When upgrading MVC version, a lot of things need to be upgraded with it, like Framework version (yours is probably 4, change it to 4.5.2, for example).

Also, try clearing and rebuilding app (I think you already did that, but doesn't hurt to check :) ).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For me this happened when i went to VS 2015. It seems that the system.web.webpages.administration.dll was remaining in the bin folder and this caused a problem. this happened when I upgraded some NUGet packages. I am unsure to which one. I deleted the .dll and this fixed the issue for me. I noticed when i reinstalled the web helpers it seemed to come back, so maybe that is the offending package?
Edit: I wanted to add that I did not find the dependency in the vbproj file in my case. I could find nowhere that my project used this .dll but all the same it seems to load up.

Comment: Thank you-Thank you-Thank You!!  I have installed/uninstalled so many packages trying to solve this, but this was my issue as well.  Great find!

Comment: Great thanks, deleting the entire contents of the bin folder and doing a rebuild solved this for me too

Comment: Scratching my head for a few hours and actually deleting the entire contents of bin folder instead of just doing a 'Clean Solution' fixed it.. thanks

Answer (score 8):

Just incase if anyone faced this issue when publishing the app to Azure app service

1. Go to settings in the publishing profile
   [image]

   2. check the checkbox "Remove additional files at destination"
      [image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

comment below two lines in site.csproj file

```
<!--<None Iclude="_bin_deployableAssemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Administration.dll" />-->

<Content Include="App_Data\XmlDocument.xml" />
```

Comment: For me the line was <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Administration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />

Answer (score 0):

for me, I solved it by removing the reference for System.Web.Administration.dll in the project. This site, pointed me to the right direction https://codedump.io/share/d2rw80bGmlwc/1/methodaccessexception-inside-systemwebwebpages-migrating-mvc-3-to-mvc-5

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue. Even after removing the System.Web.Administration.dll from the website\bin directory, I was then getting a permissions error on those DLLs.

I closed visual studio, and re-opened **in Administrator mode** (I must have missed this when opening the solution), loaded up the same solution, and then was able to rebuild successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after searching all over the place and trying different options which did not work, I simply deleted all the files from bin\ and published the site again and it worked. Many people pointed to certain .dll files but the easiest solution was what I did and the site is back up and running.

[error-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na1Py.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not a precise solution to this - but in case it's helpful - had similar error:

```
Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.<.cctor>b__0()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.WebPagesDeployment.IsExplicitlyDisabled(System.String)' failed.
```

The cause was around the following binaries:

```
\bin\System.Web.Razor.dll
\bin\System.Web.WebPages.dll
\bin\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
```

I found a version of the same asp.net site that was working (for example a QA/STAGE site - or another dev machine where this works).
Copied the binaries from here - this cleared the error.

Again - not a solution - but it might help you find the cause. Check your project references.