# Using Cloud SQL with .NET Bookshelf tutorial

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm following the bookshelf tutorial with cloud sql:
https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/getting-started/using-cloud-sql

When running the application on my localmachine the application works fine.

When the application is deployed to Compute Engine. The server shows a runtime error which can't be read.

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

doesn't help to show the error.

When connecting thru RDP and watching the application on localhost on the Remote Desktop the following error is shown:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: 


An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.



WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].



Stack Trace: 



[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +874
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +169
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +133
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +176
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +734

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +712
```

I can't declare why the application gives this error since I haven't found some kind of reference in the project to the 2.0.0.0 version of Razor.

Version 3.0.0.0 of System.Web.WebPages.Razor is included as project reference.

Is it wise to downgrade to version 2 of Razor or are there other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total solution to solve the problem is:

1. Declare binding redirects https://stackoverflow.com/a/39999353/2629901 as answered by @Mete Atamel on this post

After declaring binding redirects to following error is shown:

> Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.AddGlobalImport(System.String)' failed.

This can be solved by

2. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers with NuGet Console as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19568376/2629901

After that the following error is shown

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebMatrix.Data, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

This can be solved by

3. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data  with NuGet Console as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22587521/2629901

Answer (score 1):

So, there's a dependency to 2.0 version but you have 3.0 version installed on your system? In that case, you can try declaring a binding redirect from 2.0 to 3.0. Here's more information on how to declare binding redirects:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx